# How to animate background-image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have this animation:

```
@keyframes floating {
  from { transform: translate(0,  0px); }
  65%  { transform: translate(0, 15px); }
  to   { transform: translate(0, -0px); }    
}
```

and I want to insert this animation on background-image. How to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this approach would work for you:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/RYbGwB

The idea is that you:

(1) style the element you are working with `position:relative; overflow:hidden;` then
(2) apply the animation to an absolutely positioned pseudo element `.element:before{...}`

**HTML**

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.element{
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.element:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  animation: floating 5s infinite;
  z-index: -1;
 background-image:url(https://github.com/bradleyflood/tool-sample-testing-images/raw/master/jpg-beach-1020x670-160kb.jpg)
}


@keyframes floating {
  from { transform: translate(0,  0px); }
  65%  { transform: translate(0, 15px); }
  to   { transform: translate(0, -0px); }    
}
```

I would like to take credit for this idea, it's from [Craig Buckler](https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/) though ;)

Hope this helps!